# cannot find or make the "/Users/[USERNAME]/.local/share/Xamarin/Mono" folder on my PC drive

Tags: mono, xamarin.forms

i am trying to get a KEY for the google map v2 for my Xamarin App that i am making. I have Xamarin installed as part of my MS-Visual studio community installation but i cannot find or make the "/Users/[USERNAME]/.local/share/Xamarin/Mono" folder.Hence i cannot proceed any further.

Comment: What are you trying to do with that folder? and how is it related to a Google Map Key?

Comment: Well, i have to issue the follwing command: keytool -list -v -keystore "C:\Users\[USERNAME]\AppData\Local\Xamarin\Mono for Android\debug.keystore" -alias androiddebugkey -storepass android -keypass android

Comment: the entire procedure is available in this link : https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/android/platform_features/maps_and_location/maps/obtaining_a_google_maps_api_key/

Comment: yes, of course,  i have done that !

Comment: Yes, of course, i am substituting my username for [USERNAME]